# how can i get an 3 dimensional numpy array out of list of nesteld list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I've got a list cars and want to convert it into an multidimensional array

```
>>> cars = [[[2,1],[1,1]],[[0,2],[0,1],[0,0]],[[5,0],[5,1],[5,2]],[[1,5],[2,5]]]
>>> cars_np = np.array(cars)
>>> cars_np.shape
(4,)
>>> cars_np
array([list([[2, 1], [1, 1]]), list([[0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 0]]),
       list([[5, 0], [5, 1], [5, 2]]), list([[1, 5], [2, 5]])],
      dtype=object) # an array of lists is not what i want
>>> cars_np = np.array([np.array(car) for car in cars])
>>> cars_np.shape
(4,)
>>> cars_np
array([array([[2, 1],
       [1, 1]]),
       array([[0, 2],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0]]),
       array([[5, 0],
       [5, 1],
       [5, 2]]),
       array([[1, 5],
       [2, 5]])], dtype=object) # an array of arrays is not what i want
```

with this list it works fine:

```
>>> l = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
>>> l_np = np.array(l)
>>> l_np.shape
(2, 2, 2) # multidimensional array as expected
```

what do i have to do with the first example?

Comment: what shape do you expect?

Comment: I am not sure what the three dimensions physically mean for your example with cars. But three dimensions work for example for color pixels - x, y and a tuple for the RGB color value, so `[[[r, g, b], [r, g, b]], [[r, g, b], [r, g, b]]]` where r, g, b are color values. The shape of this array is (2, 2, 3).

Comment: a (4,3,2) dimensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy arrays must have well defined shape, eg `(2,2,2)` in your final example. Your list `cars` is a list of lists where the inner lists have length `2,3,3,2` which is inconsistent with a well defined shape for numpy.

May I suggest that you add some NaN values to your `cars` list to make all the inner lists of length 3:

```
cars = [[[2,1],[1,1],[np.nan,np.nan]], [[0,2],[0,1],[0,0]], [[5,0],[5,1],[5,2]], [[1,5],[2,5],[np.nan,np.nan]]]
np.array(cars).shape
>>>  (4, 3, 2)
```

which is likely the behaviour you are looking for. NaN values can be filtered with the function `np.isnan` and shouldn't behave like regular valid values which will make them easy to work around.

Comment: perfect! that is what i was looking for. thank you!